# PHP: Using variable inside an array that gets passed into a function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Is it possible to do something similar to the following, I've tried but couldn't get any variations of this to work:

```
$hello_all = array($str . ' World', $str . ' Universe');

function combine(&$arr){
  $str = 'Hello';
  print_r($arr);
}

combine($hello_all);
```

And I'd like to get something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Hello World [1] => Hello Universe )
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: yes, but not that way - just the other way round. The concatanation would be _IN_ a function.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? I mean, 'Hello' won't be hard coded, will it?

Comment: No, not hard coded. It's another variable but I wanted to simplify the example down to the part that I was questioning.

Comment: You could of course do a kind of templating with preg_replace and things like `array('#replace# World')`, but that would be much slower than Patrick's solution

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do it like this

```
$hello_all = array('World', 'Universe');

function combine($arr, $str){

  foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $new[] = $str.$value;
  }

  return $new;
}

$print = combine($hello_all, 'Hello ');
print_r($print);

?>
```

Comment: yes, but please put the print_r() outside of the function, and let the function just return the new array. Just for my eyes....

Comment: ...forgot the return

Comment: Yup I agree. I made the changes

Comment: Your right since the print_r is no longer in the function

Comment: This makes sense. I think I simplified my example a bit too much. But the array would be closer to this: `$hello_all = array('Hidey ho ' . $str . ' World', 'We come in peace ' . $str . ' Universe');`

Comment: Then you could go the way of a str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

Yup something like this in that case:

```
$hello_all = array('World *word*', 'Universe *word*', '*word* mom', 'Hey santa! *word* to you!');

function combine($arr, $str, $find){

  foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $new[] = str_replace($find, $str, $value);
  }

  return $new;
}

$print = combine($hello_all, 'Hello', '*word*');
print_r($print);

?>
```